# Edit slugs independently of title in Rails using FriendlyID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slug, friendly-id

Im creating a Blog Rails webapp. I decided to use the FriendlyID gem and I want to add the ability to customize the slugs on the edit view). However it seems that the slug cannot be modified by itself. Currently the slug only gets updated when the title is run and I would like to have a slug that can be independently updated and not tied necessarily to the title

Blog.rb

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: { draft: 0, published: 1 }

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, :use => [:slugged, :history]

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.blank? || title_changed?
  end
end
```

blog_controller.rb

```
def set_blog
  @blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post in the [friendly_id wiki page](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks)

Let's say you have wanted your `Blog` to be able to edit the slug independently from the title (which the slug is derived from) and that doesn't default to another field:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :temporary_slug
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug, :use => [:slugged]

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    temporary_slug_changed?
  end

 # track changes in non persisted attribute

  def temporary_slug=(value)
    attribute_will_change!('temporary_slug') if temporary_slug != value
    @temporary_slug = value
  end

  def temporary_slug_changed?
    changed.include?('temporary_slug')
  end

end
```

And an example output looks like this:

```
blog = Blog.create(title: "How Long is a Long Long Time")
blog.slug 
# nil
post = Blog.update_attributes(title: "Some other title", temporary_slug: "My favorite blog")
blog.slug 
# 'my-favorite-blog'
```

Otherwise, if you want the slug to default to a version of the title you'd be doing this instead:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, :use => [:slugged]
  validates_presence_of :title

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    if !slug?
      name_changed?
    else
      false
    end
  end
end

blog = Blog.create(title: "How Long is a Long Long Time", slug: 'how-long')
blog.slug 
# 'how-long'
blog = Blog.create(title: "How Long is a Long Long Time")
blog.slug 
# 'how-long-is-a-long-long-time'
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help! However after following the instructions i get the following output for my updated blog entry with the temporary_slug: "My favorite blog" updated:

slug: "c4f2455c-08a1-47f9-bca8-722543b52971"

It seems that the slug gets converted to some type id. Any ideas whats happening here?